# NextJS: Problem related to nested dynamic routing (/category/[label]/subcategory/[id])

Tags: next.js, url-routing

[image]

Category Path

```
http://localhost:3000/category/Municipality
```

When selecting a category [label] and then selecting the subcategory [id], I am losing the value [label] in the path, and it only shows me the following path:

```
http://localhost:3000/category/subcategory/44
```

Nextjs allows me to display the subcategory information without problems, but the path it is taking is not correct.

### I want the path to be like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/category/Municipality/subcategory/44
```

### Code: Example

```
  const path = `/category/subcategory/${directory?.id}`; // ??

  return (
    <List.Item key={directory.id}>
      <Skeleton avatar title={false} loading={isLoading} active>
        <Card cover={<Image src={`${config.SERVER_URL}${thumbnail?.attributes?.formats?.large?.url}`} />} style={{ width: 300 }} loading={isLoading}>
          <Meta
            title={<Link href={path}>{title}</Link>} // path to view subcategory information
            description={description}
          />
        </Card>

      </Skeleton>
    </List.Item>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think `[label]` should be a folder containing an index and subcategory files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the folder structure a little bit and make it like the following:

- pages

  - category

    - [label] `<-- this is a folder`

      - subcategory

        - [id].tsx
      - index.tsx

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-river-dzz9zz?file=/pages/category/%5Blabel%5D/index.js) is the link to the working example

Also in your code example, the `path` variable looks incorrect. I believe it should be something like that

```js
const path = `/category/${category.label}/subcategory/${directory?.id}`;
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it worked for me!

I had to add the new folder [label] and inside the folder add the subcategory folder.
But I also had to leave the main category file as [label].tsx, and not as index.tsx.

And in subcategory/[id].tsx I had to use the useRouter hook to access the [labe] value of the category.